# Get the latest ChangeLog token with OpenCMIS/DotCMIS

Tags: cmis, opencmis, dotcmis

I have some code that needs to know the latest ChangeToken, so I wrote:

```
session.Clear();
var token = session.RepositoryInfo.LatestChangeLogToken;
```

Unfortunately, it does not always return the latest token.
Example:

1. Start the session
2. Run the code above, I get `72`
3. Create a folder on the server
4. Start CMIS Workbench, read the token, it is `73`
5. Run the code above again while still in the same session, I get `72` <-- Problem

Is there a way to somehow "reset" the session, or clear the cache better?
I would prefer to not create a new session every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCMIS has the `Session.getLatestChangeLogToken()` method for that, which does the same.
Clearing the caches or fetching the repository info is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
session.Clear(); // Clear all caches.
session.Binding.GetRepositoryService().GetRepositoryInfos(null);

var token = session.Binding.GetRepositoryService().GetRepositoryInfo(
      this.session.RepositoryInfo.Id, null).LatestChangeLogToken;
```

The token is always up-to-date.
Not too sure whether the first two lines are needed or not.